# Is it possible to change values of a column when it is displayed into datagridview?

Tags: c#

I have a column "Status" from table members.  It has values of "active". Can I change the values to "operative" when it is displayed in the datagridview?

Answer (score 1):

You can change this in the OnRowDataBound event:

```
protected void OnRowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        TableCell status = e.Row.Cells[1];
        if (status.Text == "active")
        {
            statusCell.Text = "operative";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Narts Just keep in mind that this substitute will be done for each row on every row binding. And it maybe not clear for other developer that data has some on binding modifications.
I don't know the whole program flow you have but if you have an access to initial query that retrieves data then you can add a calculated column to this initial query or even more I think you can create a calculated column in datatable or dataview and bind it to grid.

Comment: Yeah I probably would do this differently but it seems to fit your question. Assuming you can modify your SQL, just use a CASE statement and be done with it.